# apt autoremove it's not work

Tags: update-manager

```
apt autoremove
E: Invalid operation autoremove
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/i/icu/libicu-dev_57.1-8_i386.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/u/uhd/uhd-host_3.10.2.0-3_i386.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` .. if you run apt without sudo, you ar missing superuser (root) rights.

Comment: Hm, I think that's a different issue here. When I do it without sudo I get the error `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`.

Comment: @SorenA is correct. Search for your 'are you root?' error - it's been answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are not able to run this operation, although there are some recommendations in order to achieve `apt` operations. First of all try to run it as `sudo` and then fix your repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yourRepos.list`, it looks like you don't have access to *http://deb.parrotsec.org*

`E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/i/icu/libicu-dev_57.1-8_i386.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/u/uhd/uhd-host_3.10.2.0-3_i386.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

You should fix your repositories and/or have a internet connection, then run `apt-get update` and `apt-get autoremove`